# Android Emulator not Displaying output

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new just working with some basic Android codes. My problem is that Android Emulator  is not showing any output when I run code. It takes really long and on console it sticks here

```
  [2013-03-31 03:17:55 - Helloworld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
```

and  emulator looks like this

[image]

I have waited for 5-10 minutes but it does not show output. Please guide me where the problem might be. I downloaded `sdk ADT Bundle for Windows` and  configured it as mentioned in official site.

Comment: There might be error when you are launching your app check in your console, or in logcat

Comment: even hello world project   is not working

Comment: what I am saying is when ever application unable to launch, you'll find some trace in Console, check that, if you find anything post here.

Comment: Close your AVD once.... and don't start it manually.. let the application start it..i.e close your emulator and right click on application and run or debug as android application

Comment: On very slow computers, e.g. those with a 1 GHz Pentium 4 processor, you might have some performance issues. If this is not the case: have you checked, if your main activity doesn't have any endless loops? Have you tested the `Hello World` project on a real device?

Comment: i dont have real device ..   hp corei3 laptop . Yes Hello world is not working its stuck once emulator   is loaded.

Comment: Ok, your laptop sounds ok; how much memory have you reserved for your virtual device? Shouldn't be less than 512MB ...

Comment: yes i have set it to 512

Comment: This is where  console is stuck                                          [2013-03-31 03:55:40 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, try :
Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android/Devices

Select the Emulator from the newly added Devices window, and check back your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a little debug, and set a break point on the very first line of code in your app's main activity.  Then I'd step thru and see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the similar problem, in my case I forgot to add the activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.

The following is my Manifest file for example ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testalarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testalarm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testalarm.CheckpointActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.testalarm.CheckpointActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Check if you have all required activities as <activity> under <application>

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a little bit more in your answer, such as what the AndroidManifest.xml should look like with the activity in it.